# How to angle an edge of plywood at 45 degrees?

Tags: wood, woodworking, plywood

Say you have two pieces of plywood.

the goal is:

1. to assemble the two pieces at a 90 degree angle (where 3/4 inch
   edges are touching)
2. create an angled edge sit the edges sit flush
   against each other

How can a 45 degree edge be created spanning the height or width of the plywood?

EDIT: assume edge requiring the 45 degree angle = 6ft

Comment: It's hard to cut a 45 on the edge that long, and typically a simple butt joint would be used for that corner.  Is there a reason you need the miter joint?

Comment: "How can a 45 degree edge be created spanning the height or width of the plywood?"  **What is the height or width of the plywood?**  *This would dictate whether you can use a table saw or a circular saw with a straight edge*.  How are you securing this joint ?

Comment: A rail saw can do this - and my son has done several during his build for planks 3 or 4 metres long, just need to secure the wood so it stays straight.

Comment: sounds like a job for a table saw, unless you're a lot better at using hand tools than I am.

Comment: table saw is obviously best.  How do you intend to fasten the joint? When I've done long mitered joints like that I've used biscuits to help with alignment.   But then you need a plate joiner (biscuit joiner).  short dowels can also work, you just need the template and a drill.   JPi asked why a butt joint would not do, good question.  If for appearance, you could make the butt joint slightly shy to leave room for a glue on or iron on wood  trim strip to cover the end of the plywood.

Comment: @JPhi1618, the reason relates to phi pyramidal construction, somewhat atypical to conventional woodworking I had guessed. (see work done by russia's Alexander Golod) its my understanding no metal can be used. so that half-answers the fastening questions. the structure should be flush to enhance the effect. +1 for rail saw suggestion. a google search for that resulted with "track saws", looks like I either need one of those or a solid way to stabilize the plywood/saw blade at proper angle for the duration of cut

Comment: @Jim If you can not afford or do not want to buy an expensive track saw, then As i mentioned, a circular saw and a straight edge ( clamped down ) will work if you are skilled enough to keep the fence of the saw against the strait edge. Circular saws can be set to cut at a 45 deg angle.

Comment: perfect, thanks @AlaskaMan. create an answer to be accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not have a table saw and the run out table big enough for this job and you do not have a track saw you can use a straight edge and clamps.

The ***straight edge (hear after referred to as SE )*** needs to be **rigid** so it will not flex in the middle, a long level works, but some times it so thick that the motor of the saw may not pass over it, and the clamps can also interfere. Testing is required with your saw.

I have a long SE that is not as rigid as i would like so i  have to cut a 2x4 the correct length and clamp it so it reaches the middle of the SE from the side to keep the saw from flexing the SE.

I  created a block of wood that is as wide as the distance from the edge of the saw fence to the blade so i can place one side of the block on my mark and the SE up against the block. Then i know that with the fence against the SE the blade will hit the mark.

For 45 deg cut with circular saw **a sharp blade is needed with as many teeth as you can afford**.

Because of the rotation of the blade you want the finished surface or your plywood to be on the bottom. I.E. the finshed side of the wood will be underneath and saw will be on top, this will keep the finished side from getting tear out. ( this is the opposite of a table saw )

**Go slow and keep the saw fence against the SE. Do some test cuts on scrap wood.**